# Turning from byte keyboard reading into word

Tags: assembly

I am new to this place and assembly and i want to ask a question which would help me a lot. I have a code:

```
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 0A
int 21
mov bh, 00
mov bl, byte ptr [201]
mov byte ptr[200], 0D
mov byte ptr[201], 0A
mov byte ptr[202 + bx], 24
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 09
int 21
mov ah, 4c
int 21
```

Which shows exactly what i input in keyboard, but it's only for 6 numbers. I have to make that i could input up to 8. As far i understand i need to change from byte ptr, to word, but i have no idea how to do it. Can you please explain how to do it and why. I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a string from stdin (int 21h, ah=0a) ds:dx must point to a valid buffer to store the string. This buffer has a particular format though:

```
 offset | content
--------+----------
      0 | maximum string length
      1 | will contain number of characters read
      2 | will contain the string
```

so basically you have to specify how many characters you want (at most):

```
mov byte ptr[200], 8
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 0A
int 21
```

byte ptr and word ptr (and dword ptr as well) specify how many bytes the CPU should load from the memory, so they have nothing to do with this.

Reference [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a).

Comment: Thought that i need word, because i take more than 8 bytes with more numbers. Thank you for clear explanation.